# My problem is that when i select boxes and save. But when i want to change the food i find all boxes checked or i had selected only two boxes

Tags: laravel

my controller method update :

```
 public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        
`
        $alimentaire =  Alimentaire::find($id);
        $alimentaire->categorie_id = $request->categorie_id;
        $alimentaire->title = $request->tit`l
e;
        //Enregistrement de l'image 
        if ($request->hasFile('cover')) {
            $alimentaire->cover = $request->file('cover')->store('images/posts');
        }
        $alimentaire->description = $request->description;
       
        $alimentaire->save();
       
        
        $alimentaire->ingredient()->sync($request->ingredients);

        // Mettre à jour les relations avec les tailles
        $alimentaire->size()->sync($request->sizes);
    
        // Mettre à jour les relations avec les suppléments
        $alimentaire->supplement()->sync($request->supplements);
       // dd($alimentaire->ingredient);

        return redirect()->route('alimentaires.index')->with('success', 'Aliment modifié avec succès');
    }`your text`
```

My problem is that when i select boxes and save. But when i want to change the food i find all boxes checked or i had selected only two boxes

Comment: show a sample of the request object `$request->dd()`

Comment: i try dd($request) right ?